# JSON data recognized as a string field instead of integer

Tags: python, json, encoding, findall

I use the below python code to manipulate a set of JSON files in a specified folder. I extract `nt` from the data and I want to create new key value pair. If I were to print `nt` on my screen I get values as shown below.

```
nt 223 
nt 286 
nt 315
```

These looks like integers to me. However If I use Kibana visualization tool to process it says this (i.e `NXT` is an analysed string fields). I want these values to be recognized as integers? Does this have something to do with the way I am encoding my json file (`ensure_ascii=True`) or is JSON `value` always a string?

```
#Process 'new' events to extract more info from 'Messages'
rootDir = '/home/s_parts'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
     for fname in fileList:
        fname='s_parts/'+fname
        with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            m = json_data['Msg']
            nt = int(re.findall(r"NXT:\s*([^,m)]*)",m)[0])
            json_data["NXT"] = nt
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(json_data,f,ensure_ascii=True)
```

Comment: Can you open the JSON file in a text editor and copy-paste into your question the relevant text? I suspect that your code works correctly, and that kibana is lying to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears `json.dump` alone is most likely treating everything as strings. Using `json.loads` after it should convert it into a list or dict allowing you to use the json values as integers.

Example:

```
x = json.dumps({'1': 2, '3': 4}, ensure_ascii=True, sort_keys=True)
y = json.loads(x)
print(y)
print(y['3']+1)
```

Output:

```
{u'1': 2, u'3': 4}
5
```

You could convert the `string` value to `int` without using `json.loads`, however, converting it to a list or dict with json.loads is far easier to manage and retrieve values. If you are curious about the `type` your `json.dump` result is try doing:

```
x = json.dump(json_data,f,ensure_ascii=True)
print(type(x))
```

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html

Comment: I am not talking about `keys` in JSON. I am talking about `value`

Comment: The values are converted also apparently. "The json module always produces str objects, not bytes objects. Therefore, fp.write() must support str input." - that's also mentioned on the same page linked in the answer.

Comment: There are integer `values` in my JSON file as recognized by Kibana

Comment: It is strange, however. the example I used seems to indicate that even while the json `value` may appear to be using `int` it treats it as a string. http://ideone.com/yHtcH6 (`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`)

Comment: Well. I have some value in the JSON file that are integers. Maybe it has something to do with `.metadata` ?

Comment: @liv2hak, I discovered after doing `json.dump` that making it into a list or dict using `json.loads` then works with the values being treating as integers: http://ideone.com/cAkXKi