# json.dump() changes the type from `dict` to `NoneType`

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have a small python program that I use to manipulate JSON files. I find that when I dump the manipulated data back to the JSON file using json.dump() it changes to `<type 'NoneType'>`. The original type of the data below (type of `json_data`) is `<type 'dict'>`. I am storing these JSON documents in elasticsearch and visualising it using Kibana4.Kibana4 is treating newly added integer fields as string. Has someone come across this issue before.

```
import json                                                                                                                                                                                    

fname = "json_data.txt"
with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    print(type(json_data))
    #Code to add fields to json files.   
    f.seek(0)
    x = json.dump(json_data,f,ensure_ascii=True)
    print(type(x))
```

Comment: What happens if you `print(type(json_data))` after the call to `json.dump()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json.dump()` has no return value. It writes *to* the file, not return the dumped object.

As such the default return value for a callable, `None` is returned instead.

In other words, your code is doing exactly what you asked it to do: read JSON data and parse it, the result is stored in `json_data`. You then write that Python object back into the file. The return value of `json.dump()` is irrelevant here, you still have a reference to `json_data`.

If you wanted a string value containing the JSON object, use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) (note the `s`); this returns the resulting JSON string without writing to a file:

```
fname = "json_data.txt"
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    print(type(json_data))

json_string = json.dumps(json_data)
print(type(json_string))
```

Comment: In the final paragraph and example, you mean `json.dumps`, surely.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - Could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482512/json-data-recognized-as-a-string-field-instead-of-integer. This was my original problem.

Comment: @liv2hak: out of time for now, sorry.

Comment: @Robᵩ - I actually intented to write that out to the file `f`.Now I realize it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think json.dump() has no return values. Are you maybe looking for json.dumps()